# Highlighting in Solr

Tags: c#, .net

I use Solrnet to develop a search engine. In my application, I have a field called file_contents which I use for highlighting. Am able to get the highlights without a problem. Now I need to format it. For example, if the keyword occurs multiple times in the field, I have to display it lime what google does. May be like this.

GSMArena.com: **Toshiba** GSM cellphones. ... **Toshiba** phones. **Toshiba**. Filters. Available · Coming soon · Smartphone · Touchscreen · Camera · Bluetooth · Wi-Fi ...

Multiple snippets here are separated by "...". I need to achieve something like this. Am able to get multiple snippets. But how do I deal with the separating?

Regards

Vignesh

Comment: Since you already could get all necessary information from Solr and SolrNet, this is not a question about Solr/Solrnet, but about C# / .Net in general.

Comment: And since few people are familiar with Solr and SolrNet you'll have to provide more information as to what data structures SolrNet gives you and what data structures you want.

Comment: In order to ask good questions you must always consider your audience.

Comment: @Mauricio : Sure. I will keep that in mind the next time. And regarding the query I was under the impression, Solr/Solrnet will return the snippets separated by a delimiter. Now after some browsing, I understand that this question has nothing to so with Solr/Solrnet. I blame my stupidity here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without much to go on in the question about what format the snippets data is in, assuming it's in an array called `YourArrayOfSnippets`, you'd do:

```
string joined_snippets = string.Join(" ... ", YourArrayOfSnippets);
```

And then use `joined_snippets` however you see fit.

In fact, [SolrNet has a wiki page on highlighting](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Highlighting) with an example of how you might handle highlighting results, and even shows the use of `Join`. Basically:

```
var results = solr.Query(new SolrQueryByField("features", "noise"), new QueryOptions {
    Highlight = new HighlightingParameters {
        Fields = new[] {"features"},
    }
});
foreach (var h in results.Highlights[results[0].Id]) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", h.Key, string.Join(", ", h.Value.ToArray()));
}
```